# Basic use examples of \newluachunkname, \newluabytecode and \newwhatsit (ltluatex)

Tags: luatex, latex-project

Reading [`ltluatex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/ltluatex.pdf) documentation, I see there are several new `(La)TeX` commands. Among them, I find `\newluachunkname`, `\newluabytecode` and `\newwhatsit` but I cannot think of a simple concrete use example.

My question is: can somebody provide such examples?

Comment: These are all rather specialist: for example, byte code is used to store Lua in a format file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For chunk names at least, there are somewhat minimal examples in the `ltluatexsupp` github

https://github.com/josephwright/ltluatexsupp/blob/master/examples-latex/bytecodetest.tex

for example has

```
\newluachunkname\mych
\newluachunkname\mychb
\directlua{
luatexbase.new_chunkname("luachunk")
}
\directlua \mych {
function test_stack ()
print(debug.traceback())
end
}
\directlua \mychb{
test_stack()
}
\directlua name{luachunk}{
test_stack()
}
```

which produces a log of

```
stack traceback:
        [string "mych"]:1: in function 'test_stack'
        [string "mychb"]:1: in main chunk
stack traceback:
        [string "mych"]:1: in function 'test_stack'
        [string "luachunk"]:1: in main chunk
```

showing that the Lua tracing information is prefixed by the declared chunk names when that name is passed to `\directlua`.

`examples-latex/test1-luatexbase.tex` has some `\newwhatsit` examples but I think we only have examples of bytecode use from Lua, not using `\newluabytecode`